# How do I get multiple counts based on distinct parameters in one SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with multiple medical records of relatives. I'm trying to count instances of cancer diagnoses per degree of relative.

```
CREATE TABLE Relatives
(person varchar(9), 
 relative varchar(12), 
 degree int, 
 relativeID varchar(9),
 age int, 
 CancerDiagnosis varchar(2))

INSERT INTO RELATIVES (person, relative, degree, relativeid, age, cancerdiagnosis)
VALUES ('12345678','aunt','2','54876','36','Y'),
       ('12345678','aunt','2','54876','43','Y'),
       ('12345678','cousin','3','213786','39','N'),
       ('12345678','daughter','1','128756','15','Y'),
       ('12345678','daughter','1','128756','21','Y'),
       ('12345678','daughter','1','128756','12','N'),
       ('12345678','father','1','867578','64','Y'), 
       ('98765432','cousin','3','987645','39','Y'),
       ('98765432','cousin','3','987645','40','Y'),
       ('98765432','sibling','1','123744','22','N'),
       ('98765432','mother','1','876418','64','Y'),
       ('98765432','mother','1','876418','65','Y'),
```

I expect the result:

```
  person    fdr_cancer    sdr_cancer   tdr_cancer 
12345678      2              1           0
98765432      1              0           1
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT person, 
SUM(CASE WHEN cancerdiagnosis = 'y' AND degree = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 
FDR_Cancer,
SUM(CASE WHEN cancerdiagnosis = 'y' AND degree = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 
SDR_Cancer,
sum(CASE WHEN cancerdiagnosis = 'y' AND degree = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 
TDR_Cancer
FROM Relatives 
GROUP BY person
```

How do I get this to count distinct rows by relativeID, degree, and diagnosis?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want conditional `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT person, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN cancerdiagnosis = 'y' AND degree = 1 THEN relativeid END) AS FDR_Cancer,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN cancerdiagnosis = 'y' AND degree = 2 THEN relativeid END) AS SDR_Cancer,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN cancerdiagnosis = 'y' AND degree = 3 THEN relativeid END) AS TDR_Cancer
FROM Relatives 
GROUP BY person;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of three COUNT DISTINCT you can apply DISTINCT *before* aggregation, should be more efficient:

```
with cte as 
 ( select distinct 
      person, degree, relativeid, cancerdiagnosis
   from Relatives 
 )
SELECT person, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN cancerdiagnosis = 'y' AND degree = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FDR_Cancer,
   SUM(CASE WHEN cancerdiagnosis = 'y' AND degree = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SDR_Cancer,
   sum(CASE WHEN cancerdiagnosis = 'y' AND degree = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TDR_Cancer
FROM cte 
GROUP BY person
```

It might be possible to move the `cancerdiagnosis = 'y'` as a WHERE-condititon into the CTE (but then a person where the diagnosis is `N` for *all* rows will be omitted):

```
with cte as 
 ( select distinct 
      person, degree, relativeid
   from Relatives 
   where cancerdiagnosis = 'y'
 )
SELECT person, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN degree = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FDR_Cancer,
   SUM(CASE WHEN degree = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SDR_Cancer,
   sum(CASE WHEN degree = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TDR_Cancer
FROM cte 
GROUP BY person
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers are easier to understand, but another option is to use `PIVOT`

```
SELECT 
    person
    ,[1] AS FDR_Cancer
    ,[2] AS SDR_Cancer
    ,[3] AS TDR_Cancer
FROM 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            person
            ,relativeid
            ,degree
            ,CancerDiagnosis
        FROM Relatives
    ) ps
PIVOT 
    (
        COUNT(relativeid) FOR degree IN ([1],[2],[3])
    ) AS pvt
WHERE 
    pvt.CancerDiagnosis = 'Y'
```